# Sorting of map based on arabic desc not working properly using java

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, arabic

Good day

Im trying to sort a map based on arabic desc which is one of the field in the dto. But one of the map object is not getting removed while sorting. All keys are different. Here is my code

```
public class TestArabic {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<Integer, NationalityDto> m = new HashMap<Integer, NationalityDto>();

    NationalityDto n10 = new NationalityDto();
    n10.setNatid(110);
    n10.setDesc("");
    m.put(110, n10);

    NationalityDto n2 = new NationalityDto();
    n2.setNatid(102);
    n2.setDesc("الهند");
    m.put(102, n2);
    NationalityDto n3 = new NationalityDto();
    n3.setNatid(103);
    n3.setDesc("سعودي");
    m.put(103, n3);
    NationalityDto n1 = new NationalityDto();
    n1.setNatid(101);
    n1.setDesc("مصر");
    m.put(101, n1);
    NationalityDto n4 = new NationalityDto();
    n4.setNatid(104);
    n4.setDesc("الكويت");
    m.put(104, n4);
    NationalityDto n5 = new NationalityDto();
    n5.setNatid(105);
    n5.setDesc("لبنان");
    m.put(105, n5);
    NationalityDto n6 = new NationalityDto();
    n6.setNatid(106);
    n6.setDesc("");
    m.put(106, n6);
    System.out.println(m);

    Map<Integer, NationalityDto> sortedMap = sortByValue(m);



    System.out.println("About to sort the map");
    System.out.println(sortedMap);
    List<NationalityDto> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //Add elements
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, NationalityDto> m1 : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
        list.add(m1.getValue());
    }

    Collections.sort(list, (e1, e2) -> e1.getDesc().compareTo(e2.getDesc()));

    Map<Integer, NationalityDto> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for(NationalityDto dto : list){
        map.put(dto.getNatid(), dto);
    }
    System.out.println("Sorted map");
    System.out.println(map);

}

private static Map<Integer, NationalityDto> sortByValue(Map m) {
    Map<Integer, NationalityDto> sortedMap = new TreeMap(new ValueComparator(m));
    sortedMap.putAll(m);
    return sortedMap;
}
}

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
Map<Integer, NationalityDto> map;

public ValueComparator(Map map) {
    this.map = map;
}

public int compare(Integer s1, Integer s2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ((NationalityDto) map.get(s1)).getDesc().compareTo(((NationalityDto) map.get(s2)).getDesc());
}
}
```

### Output

```
{101=NationalityDto [natid=101, desc=مصر], 102=NationalityDto [natid=102, desc=الهند], 103=NationalityDto [natid=103, desc=سعودي], 104=NationalityDto [natid=104, desc=الكويت], 105=NationalityDto [natid=105, desc=لبنان], 106=NationalityDto [natid=106, desc=], 110=NationalityDto [natid=110, desc=]}

About to sort the map

{106=NationalityDto [natid=110, desc=], 104=NationalityDto [natid=104, desc=الكويت], 102=NationalityDto [natid=102, desc=الهند], 103=NationalityDto [natid=103, desc=سعودي], 105=NationalityDto [natid=105, desc=لبنان], 101=NationalityDto [natid=101, desc=مصر]}

Sorted map

{110=NationalityDto [natid=110, desc=], 104=NationalityDto [natid=104, desc=الكويت], 102=NationalityDto [natid=102, desc=الهند], 103=NationalityDto [natid=103, desc=سعودي], 105=NationalityDto [natid=105, desc=لبنان], 101=NationalityDto [natid=101, desc=مصر]}
```

I dont understand why 106 key is having 110 object. Any ideas

Updated :

Now 106 key is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `HashMap` in the example which doesn't guarantee any order while retrieving the elements, so you won't get the elemets in expected order anyway.

So, I'd sugest the following:

- Store the elements in list
- Sort the list
- Create a `linkedHashMap` and add all the elements

Below is an example;

```
List<NationalityDto> list = new ArrayList<>();

//Add elements

Collections.sort(list, (e1, e2) -> e1.getDesc().compareTo(e2.getDesc()));

Map<Integer, NationalityDto> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for(NationalityDto dto : list){
    map.put(dto.getId(), dto);
}
```

Comment: I cant switch to list now. Because its coming as map from the web service. Thats why I have to sort from my side again. Its sorting but, one object is missing

Comment: That's alright, you can still iterate through `Map` values and add them into the list to sort.

Comment: May b you can copy my code and test in your local. You will see that one object is missing. There are two objects which has desc as empty. But when I sort the whole mao, both values should b there.. right

Comment: I have updated the code. Plz check it. 106 key is missing

Answer (score 0):

Hint on Design:

There are duplicate data of using the same Id in the Map key and in the Dto, so why not using a List of DTOs or a Set if they are unique.

List Example:

```
    List<NationalityDto> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new NationalityDto(110, ""));
    list.add(new NationalityDto(102, "الهند"));
    list.add(new NationalityDto(103, "سعودي"));
    list.add(new NationalityDto(101, "مصر"));
    list.add(new NationalityDto(104, "الكويت"));
    list.add(new NationalityDto(105, "لبنان"));
    list.add(new NationalityDto(106, ""));

    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(NationalityDto::getDesc));

    System.out.println(list);
```

SortedSet Example:

```
    SortedSet<NationalityDto> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(NationalityDto::getDesc));
    set.add(new NationalityDto(110, ""));
    set.add(new NationalityDto(102, "الهند"));
    set.add(new NationalityDto(103, "سعودي"));
    set.add(new NationalityDto(101, "مصر"));
    set.add(new NationalityDto(104, "الكويت"));
    set.add(new NationalityDto(105, "لبنان"));
    set.add(new NationalityDto(106, ""));

    System.out.println(set);
```

and in the SortedSet you don't need to sort the collection, it is already sorted after each insert operation

Comment: please check again. There is  no duplicate object

Comment: I mean using the same number in the Map entry Key as in the Natid field, Could you use List instead of Map?. I think there is no need to use the Map